# Pointer addressing to invalid content after function return

Tags: c++, assimp

I've got a problem with returning this const pointer. Using the debugger showed me that the scene is correctly imported and stored in variable scene. After returning scene, the content pointed by scene is lost and cannot be accessed by the class calling loadData().

```
const aiScene* IOHandler::loadData(const std::string& pFile){
    Assimp::Importer importer;

    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(pFile,
    aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace      |
    aiProcess_Triangulate           |
    aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
    aiProcess_SortByPType);

    return scene;
}
```

(`Importer` and `aiScene(struct)` are part of the assimp library and cannot be modified)

I assume that the scene is stored on the stack, the return call resets the stackpointer and the content is lost. How to handle such a problem in c++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to read the [documentation](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html#a174418ab41d5b8bc51a044895cb991e5).

The scene is owned by the `Importer`, so it will be destroyed when that goes out of scope. Return [`importer.GetOrphanedScene()`](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html#a60eb9042fb85bfbd61a863e131a56ecd) to take ownership, and remember to delete it when you've finished with it.

Alternatively, you could store the importer somewhere more permanent; but that might not work too well if you need to import and use many scenes at the same time.

Comment: @mikeseymour is it possible to write this scene to a file? and save time from run time?

Comment: @Amourreux: I don't use the library, but presumably that's what the [`Exporter`](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_exporter.html) is for.

Comment: @MikeSeymour can you take a look at my 
[question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17895776/1187845)

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted the problem. The problem isn't that the pointer is local & gets destroyed. The problem is that `Assimp::Importer`'s destructor destroys what the pointer is pointing to. Since the `Assimp::Importer` object gets destroyed at the end of the function, the pointer is now pointing at invalid stuff.

Why do you need a `loadData` function? Why not use `ReadFile` as suggested here - http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/usage.html

Alternately, the solution to your problem would be ensure that the `Importer` object doesn't go out of scope till your done using the `aiScene`.

One possible way may be this - make the `Importer` object a parameter to the `loadData` method.

```
const aiScene* IOHandler::loadData(Assimp::Importer & importer, 
           const std::string& pFile)
{
          const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(pFile,
          aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace        |
          aiProcess_Triangulate         |
          aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
          aiProcess_SortByPType);

     return scene;
}
```

The calling code would look like this.

```
{
    ........
    Assimp::Importer imp;
    const aiScene * p = loadData(imp, pFile);
    // use aiScene 
    ........
    // Importer object goes out of scope here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `Assimp::Importer` owns the resource returned by `ReadFile`, so when `importer` goes out of scope, the resource (memory) is released, and you end up returning a dangling pointer. You can pass it by parameter, or make it `static` so that it persists beyond the function scope, or allocate `scene` dynamically, copying the contents of what `ReadFile` returns -

```
const aiScene* scene = new aiScene(*importer.ReadFile(pFile,
aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace      |
aiProcess_Triangulate           |
aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices |
aiProcess_SortByPType));
```